# Check if array does not contain empty objects and matches array length

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to check if the length of `array 1` matches the length of `array 2`, and that `array 1` does not contain empty objects

my attempt

```
const matrixValues = _.size(array1,Object.keys(array1.map(item => item)).length !== 0) === array2.length
```

`array2: [{'somevalue': '1'}, {'somethingelse: '2'}, {'somethingmore': '3'}]`

`array1: [ {'somevalue': '1'}, {'somethingelse': '2'}, {} ]`
`array1` has a length of 3 here, but it contains an empty object, so we should return false, the empty object check should also not rely on the index of the element

Comment: you forget negative index elements, which are not taken into account by Array.length

Comment: @MisterJojo - Negative index items are not array elements.  They are just properties on the object.  Same as items indexed by a non-numeric string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the length of both arrays and for the first one use [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to look if there is for every object at least one property (so it is not empty).

**Extended:**  Same test if I delete in the first array (array3 in example) all empty objects can be done with [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let array2 =  [{'somevalue': '1'}, {'somethingelse': '2'}, {'somethingmore': '3'}];
let array1 = [ {'somevalue': '1'}, {'somethingelse': '2'}, {} ];
let array3 =  [{'somevalue': '1'}, {}, {'somethingelse': '2'}, {}, {'somethingmore': '3'}];

let result = (array1.length===array2.length) &&
    array1.every(obj => Object.keys(obj).length);
console.log('Same length without delete empty objects:', result);

let result2 = (array3.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).length).length === array2.length);
console.log('Same length with delete empty objects:',result2);
```

Comment: OP might also want to consider if filtering out  empty objects that makes array lengths the same is valid

Comment: I extended it to your wishes.